# IgnoreWarning added in vim-latex doesn't work

Tags: warnings, vim-latex

I use vim-latex suite.

After failing to fix the fonts warning in moderncv, I decided to just ignore them. Unfortunately that doesn't work for me neither. Here are relevant settings:

```
let g:tex_IgnoredWarnings = 
\'Underfull'."\n".
\'Overfull'."\n".
\'specifier changed to'."\n".
\'You have requested'."\n".
\'Missing number, treated as zero.'."\n".
\'There were undefined references'."\n".
\'LaTeX Font Warning:'."\n".
\'Citation %.%# undefined'
let g:Tex_IgnoreLevel = 8
```

I added line:
`\'LaTeX Font Warning:'."\n".` which should take care of following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available
```

Yet, it does not. I incremented IgnoreLevel, what else can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is very similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533241/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-vim-latex). Accepted answer points out that you should change character case of first `tex` to `let g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings`. Everything else is the same.